# How do I pass a mutable array of bytes to a DLL function (accessed via JNA)?

Tags: java, c++, string, dll, jna

I should note that I am very much a beginner in Java and I am suppose to transfer a project I have written in Delphi to Java. I need to use a DLL that came with the hardware I am using. The DLL have functions that gets and sends information from and to the device which are all written in C++. The device is essentially a controller of some sort. I am using the Java Native Access (JNA) to access and map the DLL functions to Java which is handled automatically for the most part.

The DLL have few functions which requires a string to be passed as a parameter and the function is supposed to modify this string. Here is an example function as described in the DLL documentation file.

```
int GetVersionStr(char *pcVers, int lMaxLen);
```

The function takes a string as a parameter, modifies this string with the current version of the device and I can use that string wherever I want. I have initially achieved this while writing this project in Delphi by just passing a string. However in Java, as I have found out, strings are immutable. I learned that usually StringBuilder gets the job done. However JNA can't seem to match StringBuilder to the C++ equivalent class of string or char*. If I could just interfere with JNA's class matching code to do something like this

```
my_c++_string = my_java_string_build.toString()
```

and equalize my StringBuilder object to the C++ string object using the "toString()" method of the StringBuilder, the problem would most likely be solved. But I don't really have a clue how to do this. Any and all solutions would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `char*` is *not* a string.  It is merely a pointer to a character.  Therefore the obvious solution is to create an array of `char` (or probably `byte`) and pass that.  When you were using Delphi, that is what you were doing -- you were not passing a string, you were passing the address of the start of your buffer.

Comment: Using a char array did solve the issue. Thank you.